# keyframe animation mesh changing color

Tags: animation, node-editor, keyframes, animation-nodes, three.js

I need to make keyframe animation from animation below to see color changes not only while rendering, does enyone know how to deal with this? 
 **The main reason is to export it in .json to use with three.js** 

 
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

.blend file and animation copied from another question:
[Animating a material change along an axis of a mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55282/animating-a-material-change-along-an-axis-of-a-mesh)

 thanks @lemon

Comment: possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75783/growing-a-shape-with-changing-color/75798#75798

Comment: Can you use armatures or shape keys?

Comment: @OmarAhmad yes, probaly shape keys may solve this

Comment: @m.ardito thanks for link, I found some useful info there