# How to animate a colour change along a section of a cylinder?

Tags: animation, node-editor, geometry

[image]

I want to animate a section of a cylinder that changes colour and follows the path of the cylinder. Below, I've quickly illustrated what I'd like. I want the green section to move left-to-right and then following the path continuing towards the camera.

How can I achieve this? I note [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55282/animating-a-material-change-along-an-axis-of-a-mesh), but it isn't quite what I'm after. It's only along one direction (X, Y or Z). I want the colour change to follow the cylinder regardless of what direction it's moving in.

I am following Maulik Sharma's suggestion and it works nicely. However, the way that I'm constructing my cylinder is causing issues with the UV unwrap. I generate the cylinder, scale it into the mirror and then difference bool the cylinder with the mirror to leave this face:
[image]

Now, I simply extrude this face along a direction:
[image]

The UV unwrap for an object like this is quite unruly and doesn't allow the 'colour' change to flow properly:

[image]

What's a better way to generate my cylinder so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: Consider UV unwrapping your object such that the path of your section corresponds to one of the axis of the UV map. Then you can use the same technique as the answer you linked, just using UV coordinates instead of generated coordinates.

Comment: Have you tried using the Geometry node -> Position vector in shaders?

Comment: @Alexis King any more information on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my answer, hope it helps:

1. UV Unwrap the object
2. Follow this node group[image]
3. You can animate the color to make it color change
4. Movement make the color move and width changes the width
5. I have attached the blend file too

P.S. Make sure you place the UV islands one after the other so that the color moves properly

Result and UV map:
[image]

In your case how you made your cylinder is not that important. Your UV Map is not that difficult to fix.

1. Make any one face rectangle by scale the vertices on x and y axis to 0
2. Select the face you corrected
3. Press L
4. Right Click
5. Click on follow active quads
6. For step by step instruction, I made a video for you:
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TZMg3nT229WVAF4RRS4pz20XnROdeJ7M/view?usp=sharing

(Blame the compression for garbage quality)

Blend File: https://pasteall.org/blend/1fbbe168afd841d093026a3c4967e20f

Comment: this is very nice and I understand what you mean RE: correct placement of UV islands. Could you have a look at my addition to the post and advise what I should do?

Comment: I edited my answer. read it

Answer (score 2):

As Alexis King says, you can unwrap your cylinder with the *Follow Active Quads* method in order to have an orthogonal grid (make sure that your topology has quads that are rather the same size):

[image]

Then give it this node setup: *Texture Coordinate (UV* output) > *Mapping > ColorRamp* (in *Constant* mode and with your main and stripe colors) > *Diffuse > Output*. Now you just need to keyframe the *Mapping* "Location" values to move the stripe along the cylinder:

[image]